# what does * in light of ...* refer to in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "in light of ..." refer to in the following passage (emphasis added)? Is it a reason for " concentrating on domestic financial development and regulation against"? Or it is complementing "against the backdrop of the...".

> The report concentrates on
>   domestic financial development and regulation against the backdrop of the
>   financial crises that were a worrisome feature of the decade and ***in light of*
>   the increasing mobility of capital that the other reports encouraged by calling for an easing of capital controls.**

[*Development Economics through the Decades: A Critical Look at 30 Years of the World Development Report*, Shahid Yusuf, page 31](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/2586/47108.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's referring to "concentrating on domestic financial development and regulation", because there's a kind of parallelism in the way that the sentence is structured.

The report concentrates on ____
against the backdrop of ____
and
in light of ___

It doesn't really make sense to use the *in light of* phrase to modify the *against the backdrop* phrase, because it doesn't make sense that way: there's no main verb there.
"The financial crises were a feature *and in light of* the increasing mobility?"  In light of the increasing mobility *what*?  That's why it doesn't make sense to read it that way.